# Server.Transfer from Global.asax not working when deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have the following code in global.asax which transfers to a static NotFound.aspx file when there is a 404 exception.  This works on my development machine, with debug or release builds.  When deploying the release build to an azure app service, instead of getting my static NotFound.aspx file I get a page with only the text: `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

I have verified that the static files are present on the azure deployment.

The code in global.asax is:

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Response.Clear();

        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;


        if (httpException != null)
        {
            ErrorLogger.Log(httpException);
            Server.ClearError();
            switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
            {
                case 404:
                    // page not found
                    Response.StatusCode = 404;
                    Server.Transfer("~/NotFound.aspx");                        
                    break;
                default:
                    Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx");                        
                    break;                    
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: you should not be redirecting from the `Global.asax` file you should have your logging in a separate class file in my opinion instead of clearing the error you should also do something like this `Exception ex = Server.GetLastError()` then after that call the logging method which will be in a utils class for example and pass in the `ex` as a param to the logging method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the Azure server environment has it's httpErrors config section defined in a way that intercepts these errors before they get to Application_Error.  You can either modify this to let the errors pass through, or use it to deal with the errors in the first place (Which seems to be the best option).  Using `responseMode="File"` you can avoid having to issue a redirect, and just supply a custom error page and the proper status code directly. This seems to be a more efficient and correct approach. 
Example:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" >
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="NotFound.html" responseMode="File"/>
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="Error.html" responseMode="File"/>
  <remove statusCode="400"/>
  <error statusCode="400" path="Error.html" responseMode="File"/>
</httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

For more info:

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors

Answer (score 0):

You could also try specifying the redirect rule in the `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <add statusCode="404" path="/NotFound.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then in your `Web.Release.config`(or other configuration you use in Azure):

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Replace" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes">
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can add your code 500 error page in a similar fashion.

Setting responseMode to Redirect makes IIS redirect the user with a 302, setting it to ExecuteURL will replace the response with the error page but keep the URL in the address bar.

Here is nice article about handling errors in this way: http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/5/custom-404-and-error-pages-for-asp-net-and-static-files/

Comment: How will that appear to the users browser? Will they get a redirect 301/302 and then load the error page with a 404? Ideally they should just get a 404 in place, with no redirect.  Also how do you handle logging the bad request with this approach?

Comment: See my edit about that, you would need to use ExecuteURL as the responseMode. For logging you should use a framework such as ELMAH. Another alternative could be registering a logging HTTP module yourself, though I find ELMAH very easy to use.